# Checkbox with RightToLeft flow direction in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Why checkbox checked mark appears with mirrored image in windows 8.1, when applying FlowDirection as RightToLeft. it is normally in other windows os.

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True" 
FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want this as same in other OS, edit the template and hard code as left to right for the Tick.

Comment: I am looking forward is this behaviour in windows8.1?

Comment: Yes it is the behaviour of 8.1

Comment: this not seems to be behavior can you please refer the Microsoft site

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on another search..

You could set your own style to the checkbox:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication21.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                    <Path FlowDirection="LeftToRight" x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1M9.97498,1.22334L4.6983,9.09834 4.52164,9.09834 0,5.19331 1.27664,3.52165 4.255,6.08833 8.33331,1.52588E-05 9.97498,1.22334z" Fill="#FF212121" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="#FF212121" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="#FFF3F9FF"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="#FF5593FF"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="#FF212121"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="#FF212121"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="#FFE6E6E6"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="#FFBCBCBC"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="#FF707070"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="#FF707070"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="#FFD9ECFF"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="#FF3C77DD"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="#FF212121"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="#FF212121"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True" 
FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Content="CheckBox" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Although the look will be slightly different but you can either go with it or change the style as well.